# autosubmit when page autorefresh jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a form with autosubmit. I want this page auto submit when it auto refresh.

```js
    window.onload=function(){
        var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 1000);

        function submitform(){
          alert('test');
          document.forms["myForm"].submit();
        }

        function autoRefresh(){
           clearTimeout(auto);
           auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method='post' action='../AddCompany' name="myForm" id="myForm" target="_myFrame">
    <p>
        <input name="test" value="test" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the action page. But why there is error `NullPointerException` for String _16

```js
        String _16 = request.getParameter("test").toString();
  Database db = (Database) getServletContext().getAttribute("db");
  try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO baru(baru)Values('"+_16+"')";
            db.updateSql(sql);
        }catch (Exception e2) {
            System.out.println(e2);
        }
  System.out.println(_16);
  response.sendRedirect("pages/cobain.jsp")
```

> And how to fix it?

Comment: BTW, Javascript has `setInterval()`, you don't need to reschedule via `setTimeout()` all the time.

Comment: `request.getParameter("test")` returns String , no need to use `toString()` again.

Comment: @JohannesJander can you give me sample?

Comment: Come on, that's one minute with google. There's millions of examples out there.

Comment: ok tq @JohannesJander

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try and call SumbitForm() in the autorefresh method?

```
function autoRefresh(){
   clearTimeout(auto);
   auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 1000);
   sumbitForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `<input name="test" value="test" />` is missing the `type` parameter. You need `<input name="test" type="text" value="test" />`.

And try setting it's value via JS: `document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value="testVal";`

Comment: where I must set that js?

Comment: in your `window.onload` func

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value="testVal";
        var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 1000);

        function submitform(){
          alert('test');
          document.forms["myForm"].submit();
          
        }
  
        function autoRefresh(){
           clearTimeout(auto);
           auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 1000);
        }
    }
</script>

Comment: Exactly - and don't forget to make that input type `text`